# How to Install/Use/Implement Less on Window 8?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

**The question says it all really,**

How on earth do i install Less, i've been reading and i'm pretty confused. Do i need to install Node first? Do i need to install ruby?

I've got as far as downloading the less.js_master.zip. Unzipping and having al look in all the different folders.

Can't i just include a JS file on my page like so?

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The reason i wan to install less is because i want to use the bootstrap.css without it ruining my styles so the theory is i could use less like so.

```
#ContainerWithBootboox {      
   @import "bootstrap.css"; //import bootstrap
}
```

Comment: you can use client-side less for that if you want to. 
http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage
There should be a dist folder in the less.js_master.zip where you can pick you less.js version you want to include.

Comment: yea founds the dist folder, guessing the newest version would be best.  Would the js file allow me to include @import "bootstrap.css"; in my CSS?

Comment: if you do the @import in a .less file after the <script src="less.js" />, yes.